# SQL - Creating a timeline for each ID (Vertica)

Tags: sql, date, datetime, vertica

I am dealing with the following problem in SQL (using Vertica):

**In short** -- Create a timeline for each ID (in a table where I have multiple lines, orders in my example, per ID)

**What I would like to achieve** -- At my disposal I have a table on historical order date and I would like to compute new customer (first order ever in the past month), active customer- (>1 order in last 1-3 months), passive customer- (no order for last 3-6 months) and inactive customer (no order for >6 months) rates.

**Which steps I have taken so far** -- I was able to construct a table similar to the example presented below:

```
CustomerID  Current order date  Time between current/previous order First order date (all-time) 
001         2015-04-30 12:06:58 (null)                              2015-04-30 12:06:58
001         2015-09-24 17:30:59 147 05:24:01                        2015-04-30 12:06:58
001         2016-02-11 13:21:10 139 19:50:11                        2015-04-30 12:06:58
002         2015-10-21 10:38:29 (null)                              2015-10-21 10:38:29
003         2015-05-22 12:13:01 (null)                              2015-05-22 12:13:01
003         2015-07-09 01:04:51 47 12:51:50                         2015-05-22 12:13:01
003         2015-10-23 00:23:48 105 23:18:57                        2015-05-22 12:13:01
```

*A little bit of intuition*: customer 001 placed three orders from which the second one was 147 days after its first order. Customer 002 has only placed one order in total.

**What I think that the next steps should be** -- I would like to know for each date (also dates on which a certain user did not place an order), for each CustomerID, how long it has been since his/her last order. This would imply that I would create some sort of timeline for each CustomerID. In the example presented above I would get 287 (days between 1st of May 2015 and 11th of February 2016, the timespan of this table) lines for each CustomerID. **I have difficulties solving this previous step.** When I have performed this step I want to create a field which shows at each date the last order date, the period between the last order date and the current date, and what state someone is in at the current date. For the example presented earlier, this would look something like this:

```
CustomerID Last order date     Current date        Time between current date /last order State
001        2015-04-30 12:06:58 2015-05-01 00:00:00 0 00:00:00                            New
...
001        2015-04-30 12:06:58 2015-06-30 00:00:00 60 11:53:02                           Active
...
001        2015-09-24 17:30:59 2016-02-01 00:00:00 129 11:53:02                          Passive
...

...
002        2015-10-21 17:30:59 2015-10-22 00:00:00 0 06:29:01                            New
...
002        2015-10-21 17:30:59 2015-11-30 00:00:00 39 06:29:01                           Active
...

...
003        2015-05-22 12:13:01 2015-06-23 00:00:00 31 11:46:59                           Active
...
003        2015-07-09 01:04:51 2015-10-22 00:00:00 105 11:46:59                          Inactive
...
```

*At the dots there should be all the inbetween dates but for sake of space I have left these out of the table.*

When I know for each date what the state is of each customer (active/passive/inactive) my plan is to sum the states and group by date which should give me the sum of new, active, passive and inactive customers. From here on I can easily compute the rates at each date.

*Anybody that knows how I can possibly achieve this task?*

**Note** -- If anyone has other ideas how to achieve the goal presented above (using some other approach compared to the approach I had in mind) please let me know!

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  Are you trying to accomplish your "goal"?  Are your trying to get "what I want"?  I would suggest that you delete this question.  Then ask another question with sample data, desired results, and a clear statement of what you are asking.

Comment: If you have a table with two columns (CustomerId and OrderDate) it's easy to build a query to produce: CustomerID, FirstOrderDate, LastOrderDate, CurrentDate and Status (New/Active/Inactive). Is this what you're looking for? Customer status (based on CurrentDate - LastOrderDate) will change every day... ok?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have edited my post and tried to clarify both my headers and the example given in my post. Could you please let me know whether my question is now clear?

Comment: @mauro I indeed would like something that you describe. I now have for each CustomerId one or multiple lines, with one each line an OrderDate. I would like to know at each day from the first order placed in my database until today all the rates. The customer status indeed changes everyday based on the CurrentDate and the LastOrderDate a product was ordered by that particular CustomerId. Any thoughts on how I can tackle this?

Comment: @user5818317  suppose a customer did place his order one year ago and you want the Status for this customer "__each day from the first order placed in my database until today__" then... you will get 365 columns in output. And... the number of columns will be just 30 for another customer that sent its order one month ago...

Comment: @mauro I was thinking to create a row for each customer/date combination instead of a column. For a customer that placed his first order a year ago there would be 365 rows, for a customer that placed his first order a month ago there would be 31 rows, etc.. Then there is only 1 column named 'ActivityStatus' which computes the difference between that CurrentDate and the LastOrderDate for each row and assigns the corresponding status. I know it is a bit to produce a line for each day for each customer since a particular customer places its first order, but I don't know how else it could be done.

Comment: @TomasG. this is much better. Side question... is TomasG the same as user5818317 (OP)?

Comment: @mauro Yes, it is. OT: Even though I have the idea of creating, for example, 365 rows for the customer who placed his first order a year ago, I have not yet been able to execute this because I do not know how. Any thoughts on how I could do this?

Comment: @TomasG please check my answer here below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Suppose you start from a table like this:

```
SQL> select * from ord order by custid, ord_date ;
 custid |      ord_date       
--------+---------------------
      1 | 2015-04-30 12:06:58
      1 | 2015-09-24 17:30:59
      1 | 2016-02-11 13:21:10
      2 | 2015-10-21 10:38:29
      3 | 2015-05-22 12:13:01
      3 | 2015-07-09 01:04:51
      3 | 2015-10-23 00:23:48
(7 rows)
```

You can use Vertica's Timeseries Analytic Functions TS_FIRST_VALUE(), TS_LAST_VALUE() to fill gaps and interpolate last_order date to the current date:

Then you just have to join this with a Vertica's TimeSeries generated from the same table with interval one day starting from the first day each customer did place his/her first order up to now (current_date):

```
select 
    custid, 
    status_dt,
    last_order_dt,
    case 
        when status_dt::date - last_order_dt::date < 30 then case
            when nord = 1 then 'New' else 'Active' end
        when status_dt::date - last_order_dt::date < 90 then 'Active'
        when status_dt::date - last_order_dt::date < 180 then 'Passive'
        else 'Inactive'
    end as status
from ( 
    select 
        custid,
        last_order_dt,
        status_dt,
        conditional_true_event (first_order_dt is null or
                                last_order_dt > lag(last_order_dt))
            over(partition by custid order by status_dt) as nord
    from (
        select 
            custid, 
            ts_first_value(ord_date) as first_order_dt ,
            ts_last_value(ord_date) as last_order_dt ,
            dt::date as status_dt
        from 
            ( select custid, ord_date from ord 
              union all
              select distinct(custid) as custid, current_date + 1 as ord_date from ord
            ) z timeseries dt as '1 day' over (partition by custid order by ord_date)
         ) x
      ) y
where status_dt <= current_date
order by 1, 2
;
```

And you will get something like this:

```
   custid | status_dt  |    last_order_dt    | status  
  --------+------------+---------------------+---------
        1 | 2015-04-30 | 2015-04-30 12:06:58 | New
        1 | 2015-05-01 | 2015-04-30 12:06:58 | New
        1 | 2015-05-02 | 2015-04-30 12:06:58 | New
        ...
        1 | 2015-05-29 | 2015-04-30 12:06:58 | New
        1 | 2015-05-30 | 2015-04-30 12:06:58 | Active
        1 | 2015-05-31 | 2015-04-30 12:06:58 | Active
        ...
        etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! There are still two small 'issues' that haven't been completely solved. 

First of all, your query only allows customers to become passive/inactive after at least 3 months since their final order. This implies that if a customer places his first order on January 1st and does not order for another 6 months (next order at July 1st), he is still considered 'active' the full 6 months, while after April 1st this customer should be considered as 'passive' since 3 months passed and he hasn't ordered since. His status should change to 'active' from July 1st onwards.

Comment: The second issue that still hasn't been solved is the fact that a complete new customer should first be considered as 'new' before becoming active one month after his first order placed. If he in the future places another order, he should then only get the status 'active' instead of 'new'.

Comment: @TomasG I see your point. You won't believe it but this actually simplify my SQL. As you have seen I get FIRST/LAST_VALUEs partitioned by CUSTID and ordered by ORD_DATE using the **framing clause** `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` because I originally thought you wanted to refer everything to the very last order date. Now, with your further explanation, (that makes sense to me), I'm going to remove this framing clause and leave the order clause so the WindowFunctions will use by default "ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW". And this is what you need...